# python script opening multiple terminals, but only executing command in one

Tags: python, linux, terminal, syntax, syntax-error

I'd like my script to open 3 terminals and execute different commands in each, but all it does is run an nmap scan in the original terminal and opens 3 blank terminals.

```
import subprocess

TARGET_IP_ADDRESS = "IPHERE"

terminal_windows = []

for i in range(3):

    terminal_windows.append(subprocess.Popen(["gnome-terminal"]))

subprocess.run(["nmap", "-T5", "-A", "-p-", "--min-rate=500", TARGET_IP_ADDRESS], check=True, stdin=terminal_windows[0].stdin)

subprocess.run(["whatweb", TARGET_IP_ADDRESS], check=True, stdin=terminal_windows[1].stdin)

subprocess.run(["gobuster", "dir", "http://" + TARGET_IP_ADDRESS + "/", "--wordlist", "/usr/share/dirb/wordlists/common.txt"], check=True, stdin=terminal_windows[2].stdin)
```

Comment: You can supply the command to run as an argument to `gnome-terminal`; this would simplify your code to basically trivial.

Comment: Running commands in separate windows is a common beginner requirement, but really not scalable. A more versatile solution is to run background commands with output to a log file, which you can then examine or `tail -f` etc from any terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wait for the NMAP scan to finish, the whatweb command will start, followed by gobuster in that same terminal.

What you did there was open 3 blank terminals in the for loop, then sequentially run terminal commands in the current terminal.

Just execute 3 subprocess calls.

```py
import subprocess

TARGET_IP_ADDRESS = "IPHERE"
ls_cmd = []
ls_cmd[0] = f"""nmap -TS -A -p- --min-rate=500 {TARGET_IP_ADDRESS}; echo; read -p "Press enter to continue....";"""
ls_cmd[1] = f"""whatweb {TARGET_IP_ADDRESS}; echo; read -p "Press enter to continue....";"""
ls_cmd[2] = f"""gobuster dir http://{TARGET_IP_ADDRESS}/ --wordlist /usr/share/dirb/wordlists/common.txt; echo; read -p "Press enter to continue....";"""

_ = [subprocess.run(f"gnome-terminal -e '{cmd}'", shell=True) for cmd in ls_cmd]
```

Comment: Now it opens 3 separate terminals, but they close 0.5 seconds after opening.

Comment: ok. you can add a pause with `read -p "Press enter to continue....";`
   let me edit my answer.